# Как быстро проверить валидность ссылки

Tags: python, url, big-data, jupyter-notebook

Занимаюсь предобработкой более 10 миллионов ссылок в Jupyter notebook на питоне, хотелось бы узнать наиболее быстродейственный способ проверить корректность ссылки. Из тех, что удалось попробовать:

```
import urllib.request 
def is_valid(url, qualifying=None):
qualifying = min_attributes if qualifying is None else qualifying
token = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
return all([getattr(token, qualifying_attr)
            for qualifying_attr in qualifying])
```

Разбирает ссылку по частям, работает быстро, но выдает такие вещи:

```
    is_valid('http://http://апревлупупц')
    True
```

---

```
    def is_valid(url):
     try:
      urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      return True
     except Exception:
      return False
```

Открывает каждую ссылку, срабатывает точно, но пашет очень медленно

P. S.  Django в Jupyter не работает, и его библиотеки, соответственно, тоже

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что `http://http://апревлупупц` является некорректным? Я вижу ссылку на сайт с адресом `http` и пропущенным необязательным номером порта — в локальной сети сайт `http://http/` очень даже может существовать, а указанная вами ссылка — работать.

Comment: Цитата из [спецификации WHATWG](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-port-string): «A URL-port string must be zero or more ASCII digits.» Слово «zero» намекает, что отсутствие порта после двоеточия — это нормально. Браузеры тоже считают такую ссылку корректной, я проверил

Comment: Хм, ну я имела ввиду ссылка считается корректной, если ее можно открыть, тем более речь идет о том, какой товар просматривал клиент, а без корректно открывающейся ссылки невозможно это выяснить

Comment: Тогда медленный urllib.request.urlopen это единственный возможный вариант

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать..

Comment: Но вы всегда можете дописать дополнительные проверки для своих нужд вида «если ссылка начинается на `http://http://`, то считать её некорректной» и тем самым немного ускорить её обработку, но тут мы уже не помощники — вам виднее, какие ссылки корректные, а какие нет, лично для вас

Comment: Попробуйте https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.url Я проверил немного, в том числе и на этой ссылке `http://http://апревлупупц` -  он считает ее невалидной. Возможно, будет точнее, чем ваше первое решение.
Также рассмотрите возможность использования многопоточности. Но если собираетесь открывать каждую ссылку и все они ведут на один и тот же домен, то не стоит.

Comment: validators - это библиотека django, а с django в Jupyter notebook проблемы - его просто так не подключишь

Comment: Та, на которую я дал ссылку - отдельная библиотека. Джанго там в зависимостях нет.

Comment: Я установила  библиотеку, проверила ссылки на корректность данным методом - в принципе, он действительно не допускает наличие странных символов, но все 10000000 ссылок, имеющиеся у меня, были опознаны как корректные, в то время, как метод  urllib.request.urlopen(url) все-таки кое-на-что ругался. Думаю, я прекращу на этом свои придирки к ссылкам - данные старые, четырехлетней давности, поэтому вполне возможно, что некоторые страницы не отображаются